# Default Mouse cursor lagging in Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, mouse

Could someone please help -  I have Ubuntu22.04 LTS running in dual boot.primary as Ubuntu.

Sometimes the default mouse(which is controlled by the touchpad) lags automatically and responses slow and irritating. but in 1-2 minutes it starts working normal.

I have checked so many forums , questions, settings, configurations nothing is helping me out.  I suspected this has to do something with my NVIDIA GTX 1650 graphics card. I have restored everything freshly, inxi -G is also showing nvidia being used.

All the drivers are updated. nothing to update. nothing is in cron, or startup or in background jobs. Tried zoom out, refresh rate default and whatever I could.

Does someone else facing this issue? could this be related to the any specific application which is making it slow responsive.

---

Below are the configurations:

intel - i5 11th gen 12 cores

Nvidia - GTX 1650 graphics

16G/512G

Dual boot- windows and ubuntu22.04